# How to display a table of data in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

This is my second time working with [Windows Presentation Foundation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation).

Here is what I have. First, I am storing a [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) List<Tuple<int,date>> object in a variable, which I will probably need to break down more into maybe a string to display the data in the [XAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Application_Markup_Language). The display should have a column for the int values and a column for the corresponding date values.

**The problem**

I am having difficulty figuring out what type of control to use to display the data, such as a listview, textbox, etc.  What would be the best option for displaying the data?

The Control would eventually need a scroll bar because I will be joining this JSON array object with more of the same type, just with adjacent columns.

Let me know if this is unclear, or more information is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go for `DataGrid` as there are Rows and Column in it and a collection can directly be provided as its datasource.

Comment: Thanks Nikhil, that was very helpful! I found great tutorial describing DataGrid. here [wpf tutorials](http://www.wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html)